# How to set Position of a textview on the customview of android

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I am using below code to set text on the canvas..But now i want to know how to set the position of the text at the bottom of the layout..

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext()); 
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setText(DetailsActivity.temp_desc);
    textView.setLines(10);
    textView.setSingleLine(false);
    layout.addView(textView);
    layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    layout.layout(0,100, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

Using this code i am getting text on position of (0,0) but i want to set it to (0,400) how can i achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is two sample code for draw text on canvas..

**1)Draw TextView on Canvas**

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext()); 

textView.setText(DetailsActivity.temp_desc);
textView.setMinLines(1);

canvas.translate(0,bitmap.getHeight());
textView.layout(0, 0, 500, 150);
textView.draw(canvas);
```

**2)Draw text on canvas**

```
canvas.drawText("Value",x_position, y_position, your paint object);
```

Comment: complete canvas is replacing..I am already have an image i want to get the text at the bottom of the image

Comment: Can you help me in inserting the `TextView` at certain co-ordinates of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to set a view to a specific position, don't use Linear Layout. Use Relative Layout, LinearLayout is as the name indicates, Linear...
Anyways it's extremely bad practise doing layouts in java, you should do them in the xml

Comment: since i am drawing text on canvas i am using so!!

Comment: Yeah so make that in the layout, and just pull out the view which canvas you need to draw on ?

Answer (score -2):

You can set the x and y coordinate of a view

see this link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX)

OR use this code with absolute layout

```
TextView txt = new TextView(screenContext);
txt.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width,height, calculatedX,calculatedY));
```

OR
For canvas while drawing use this

```
 canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: We can add text only by using `drawText` function. He wants to add `TextView` at a certain co-ordinates.